# Spring boot Poller for AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

What is the best way to call a method continuously after a fixed interval?

I want to design a Poller that can pull messages from AWS SQS automatically after a defined time interval.

Any good suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "method continuously after a fixed interval"? Can you explain more, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There are two polling mechanisms short polling - if you are expecting data more frequently and long polling if less frequently.
You should use something mixed of the above i.e
pull recursively in the timeout of 10ms,
If pull contains any message(successful pull) continue polling with the same speed else
change a timeout to let say 5000ms.
Sample:

```
//timeout is in ms
timeout = 10;
function pullFromSQS() {
  message = sqs.pull();
  if (message.length) {
    processMessage(message);
    timeout = 10;
  } else {
    timeout = 5000;
  }
  wait(timeout);
  pullFromSQS();
}
```

you can change the timeout as per your convenience for better optimization (both cost and performance)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDK provided by AWS to do polling of messages

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.ReceiveMessageRequest;

public class SQSRealtimePoller implements Runnable {


public static final int MAX_MESSAGES = 10;

public static final int DEFAULT_VISIBILITY_TIMEOUT = 15;

//Value greater that 0 makes it long polling, which will reduce SQS cost
public static final int WAIT_TIME = 20;
public static final int PROCESSORS = 2;

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
private String queueUrl;

private AmazonSQS amazonSqs;

ArrayBlockingQueue<Message> messageHoldingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Message>(
        1);

public SQSRealtimePoller(String topic, String queueUrl
       ) {
    this.queueUrl = queueUrl;
    this.amazonSqs = getSQSClient();
    messageHoldingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Message>(PROCESSORS);
    //process more than 1 messages at a time. 
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(PROCESSORS);

}

@Override
public void run() {
    ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest()
            .withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
            .withMaxNumberOfMessages(MAX_MESSAGES)
            .withVisibilityTimeout(DEFAULT_VISIBILITY_TIMEOUT)
            .withWaitTimeSeconds(WAIT_TIME);
    while(true){
        try {
            List<Message> messages = amazonSqs
                    .receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
            if (messages == null || messages.size() == 0) {
                // If there were no messages during this poll period, SQS
                // will return this list as null. Continue polling.
                continue;
            } else {
                for (Message message : messages) {
                    try {
                        //will wait here till the queue has free space to add new messages. Read documentation
                        messageHoldingQueue.put(message);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            try {
                                Message messageToProcess = messageHoldingQueue
                                        .poll();
                               //Process your message here 
                                
                                System.out.println(messageToProcess);
                                
                                //Delete the messages from queue
                                    amazonSqs.deleteMessage(queueUrl,
                                            messageToProcess
                                                    .getReceiptHandle());
                                
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    executor.execute(run);
    }}
            }       catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
    
}
}

//Make this singleton
public static AmazonSQS getSQSClient(){
    ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();
    try {
        credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                "location , and is in valid format.",
                e);
    }

    AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                           .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                           .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                           .build();
    return sqs;
}}
```